# Java Simplified Encryption with own Encryption algorithm

Tags: spring-boot, algorithm, properties, jasypt

I see that many using jasypt to encrypt the application.properties file in spring boot. Can I use my own algorithm for that? If yes then can you show me how, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Jasypt FAQ](http://www.jasypt.org/faq.html#does-it-implement-or-include-cryptographic-algorithms):

> Jasypt by itself does not implement nor distribute in any of its forms any cryptographic algorithms. It simply uses the algorithms already present in the users' Java installations via the Java Cryptography Extension.

Here is a link to the official Java 9 documentation about [How to Implement a Provider in the Java Cryptography Architecture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/security/howtoimplaprovider.htm) and another link to an example of [Building a custom Java Crypto Provider](https://reinkrul.nl/blog/java/crypto/provider/2019/11/01/custom-java-crypto-provider.html).